# Is it possible retrieve follower list from new instagram-graph-api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

is it possible retrieve instagram follower list from new instagram graph api?
It seen that instagram API are deprecated.
do you know another method to retrieve instagram follower?

Answer (score 2):

There is no API to get the list of followers for Instagram anymore. This is for privacy reasons, users who did not specifically authorize your App should not show up anywhere in any API call.

Everything you CAN do with the API is listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference

Comment: _users who did not specifically authorize your App_
If I want to fetch followers of my own IG account? I do authorize my app to fetch followers of my own account, will it work?

Comment: there´s no api endpoint for it, so of course it will not work

Comment: is it possible to fetch just my Instagram follower count only once I authenticate my app.

Comment: sure, just check out the api reference about that.

Comment: @luschn So you only get the count and not followers list even if its our own Instagram account ?

Comment: exactly, for privacy reasons. same goes for fans of facebook pages, for example.