# Retrieve follower list using the new Instagram Graph API

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Is it possible to retrieve my own follower/following list from the new instagram graph api? I know that the old API is deprecated, but is there any working method for this?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56136210/is-it-possible-retrieve-follower-list-from-new-instagram-graph-api

Comment: @DavidChopin - So the answer is "no"? There is no way to see the following/followers list, even if the user/business account authorize somehow with my app?

Comment: Doesn't look like it https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/